# With TikZ, how do I use a matrix to position verticies of a graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-matrix

How do I use the matrix library to position the vertices of a graph?

In the manual, it says to use the matrix library if I need advanced alignment of vertices while using the graph library, but it doesn't show how.

Here is the graph I want to draw:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={empty nodes,draw,circle}]
  {
    v1 -> {v2, v3, v4};
    v2 -> {v5, v6};
    v3 -> {v1, v7},
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I want to use the graph library with the matrix library.

Comment: Can you add a MWE? Have you used TikZ before?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, can you show sketch of your graph? Is it  really need to be drawn as matrix?

Comment: I am sorry, what is "MWE"?

Comment: I don't have to use a matrix, but I am following the manual instruction.

Comment: Could you please indicate manual version and page number?

Comment: It does, actually, see section 5.3 of http://ctan.mackichan.com/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your code, so as to include libraries `chains` and `matrix`, and include a second `figure` with a graph holding the same nodes, but they are:

1. Positioned in a matrix.
2. Drawn their arrows.

You can modify the distance between rows and columns in the definition of the matrix.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
% two new libraries
\usetikzlibrary{chains, matrix}
\begin{document}

% the original figure, untouched
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph[nodes={empty nodes,draw,circle}]
  {
    v1 -> {v2, v3, v4};
    v2 -> {v5, v6};
    v3 -> {v1, v7},
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

% the new figure, with a matrix and then the arrows
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (ps) [matrix of nodes, column sep=8mm, row sep=6mm,nodes={draw,circle}] {
      \node (v1) {}; & \node (v2) {}; \\
                     & \node (v3) {}; \\
                     & \node (v4) {}; \\
      \node (v5) {}; &                \\
      \node (v6) {}; &                \\
      \node (v7) {}; &                \\
    };
    \graph [use existing nodes] {
      v1 -> {v2, v3, v4};
      v2 -> {v5, v6};
      v3 -> {v1, v7};
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The main pages from the documentation (version 3.0.1a) are:

- Matrix: page 70.
- Graph with arrows: pages 71-73.